# VBScript / SQL help needed with query that joins three tables

Tags: sql, vbscript, dbase

I'm trying to build a query that will connect three tables and I want to run this query via VBscript.

This is my working version:

```
 sSQL = "SELECT OPNPOS.FUND, SECRTY.TKR, SECRTY.ISIN, OPNPOS.QTY, OPNPOS.LCL_ACCINC, PRIHST.PRICE / SECRTY.FACTOR AS CENA FROM (OPNPOS INNER JOIN SECRTY ON OPNPOS.TKR = SECRTY.TKR) INNER JOIN PRIHST ON SECRTY.TKR = PRIHST.TKR WHERE OPNPOS.FUND IN " & sFUND & " AND PRIHST.PRCDATE = #" & sDATA & "# ORDER BY OPNPOS.FUND"
```

I need to change this query in order to see every element from OPNPOS table so I would change

```
FROM OPNPOS INNER JOIN
```

to:

```
FROM OPNPOS LEFT JOIN
```

but it gives me an error.
Error: Join expression not supported.
Code: 80004005

I know that there are some ways to workaround this but I've tried a lot of combinations and get no success ;/

Anyone can help me?

This is a bigger part of my VBScript:

```
Option Explicit

dim sDATA
sDATA = InputBox("Podaj datę w formacie MM/DD/YYYY.")

dim sPATH
sPATH = "M:\MFWIN\Data"

dim sFUND
sFUND = "('FOM','KRAKOWIA')"

dim sSQL 
sSQL = "SELECT OPNPOS.FUND, SECRTY.TKR, SECRTY.ISIN, OPNPOS.QTY, OPNPOS.LCL_ACCINC, PRIHST.PRICE / SECRTY.FACTOR AS CENA FROM (OPNPOS INNER JOIN SECRTY ON OPNPOS.TKR = SECRTY.TKR) INNER JOIN PRIHST ON SECRTY.TKR = PRIHST.TKR WHERE OPNPOS.FUND IN " & sFUND & " AND PRIHST.PRCDATE = #" & sDATA & "# ORDER BY OPNPOS.FUND"


dim conn, rs

Set conn = createobject("adodb.connection") 
Set rs = createobject("adodb.recordset") 
conn.Open "Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;Dbq="&sPATH 
rs.Open sSQL,conn
```

Comment: MS Access? Something to do with (absent) brackets, perhaps (around conditions and/or joins).

Comment: What does the value of `sFUND` look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you need to say:

```
Left Outer Join
```

Instead of just

```
 Left Join
```

Comment: As far as I know the keyword OUTER is optional and it makes no difference if I add it or not.